# unix linux shellscript programming printing input arguments containing multiple words

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to write a shell script for which 1st 2nd and 3rd...n argument contains multiple words

```
MAILING_LIST="abc@gmail.com xyz@gmail.com zed@gmail.com"
echo $MAILING_LIST
mailing "Error in Job"  " There were some records that couldn't be loaded into DB" " " $MAILING_LIST
```

Now i only want to print my mailing list in the function so that i can use that to send the email

obviously no of mails in mailing list can change and so forth .

Kindly help me with this issue.

P.S if i use `echo $#` it gives me no of **args as 6** 
now my requirement is to print/get the mailing list only in my function ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the variable in quotes, since arguments are separated with spaces:

```
echo "$MAILING_LIST"
mailing "Error in Job"  " There were some records that couldn't be loaded into DB" " " "$MAILING_LIST"
```

Just like you did with `"Error in Job"`. If you had left those quotes out, there would have been eight arguments.

Comment: It does not solve my issue ... my question is to wap that will get only emails in the specified function... if you would provide me with a similar sample that would be of great help..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I have a function which gets some n input arguments comprising of 2 or more words each ... now it will be always the case that i don't have to consider the first four arguments (say comprising of 20 words total ) my requirement is to only get the mail id's so i can send them the mail .
 In the function i don't want to consider the first four arguments and only consider the email id's that can be the last argument how can i achieve that in the programme.
as i'm not able to achieve that using for /while /awk .

Comment: Do you want to split a space-separated string?

Comment: @Sunil Here is one such SO question: [How do I split a string on a delimiter in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash).